# Using Eval If/Else/EndIf in GridView causes error Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind()

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval, databinder

I am trying to pro grammatically alter a value in a GridView based on a returned database value.

The database value "is_zero_minutes_task" is Boolean. If True I wish to display a "0" and if False I wish to display the value returned in "MinutesTaken".

My code:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRecentJobs" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString_LIVE_customer_support %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString_LIVE_customer_support.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT customer_name, start_time, end_time, is_zero_minutes_task, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time,end_time) AS MinutesTaken FROM time_recorder_jobs WHERE (time_recorder_jobs.deleted = @deleted) AND (time_recorder_users.company_id = @companyid) ORDER BY end_time">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="@deleted" DefaultValue="0" Type="Object" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="companyid" SessionField="CompanyID" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewRecentJobs" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRecentJobs" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" CellSpacing="4" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
        AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="customer_name" HeaderText="customer_name" 
                SortExpression="customer_name">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="start_time" HeaderText="start_time" 
                SortExpression="start_time">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="end_time" HeaderText="end_time" 
                SortExpression="end_time">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MinutesTaken" SortExpression="MinutesTaken">
                <ItemTemplate>
<%If Eval("is_zero_minutes_task").ToString = True Then%>
                    <asp:Label ID="MinutesTaken" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
<%Else%>
                    <asp:Label ID="MinutesTaken" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MinutesTaken") %>'></asp:Label>
<%End If%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I also tried using:

```
<%If DataBinder.Eval(GridViewRecentJobs.DataItem, "is_zero_minutes_task") = True Then%>
```

But that presents the error of "'DataItem' is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'"

Comment: Are you using vb or c# in code behind?

Comment: I'm using VB in the code behind (but I haven't used any code behind for this part so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MinutesTaken" SortExpression="MinutesTaken">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="MinutesTaken" runat="server" Text='<%# If((Eval("is_zero_minutes_task") = 1), "0", Eval("MinutesTaken"))%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```